# Not able to update UI thread in android

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface

I have try to update my TextView in Thread, but not able to do, below code shows my try

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    String add = null;

    public void run() {
        add = Util.getLocationCityName(String.valueOf(ltlng.latitude),String.valueOf(ltlng.longitude));

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                LogUtil.d("add" + add);//i can get the add value
                vImei.setText(add);
            }
        });
    }
};

new Thread(runnable).start();
```

i can able to get the add value which is inside handler but values are not update to my textview, dont know what mistake i have done

Comment: did u tried `runOnUiThread(new Runnable)` method

Comment: I have tried no luck :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to init Handler with looper

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

Also you can try :

```
private LooperThread mLooperThread;

class LooperThread extends Thread
{
    public Handler mHandler;

    public void run()
    {
        Looper.prepare();

        mHandler = new Handler()
        {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg)
            {
                vImei.setText(msg.getData().getString("ADD"));
            }
        };

        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

> create Looper :

```
    mLooperThread = new LooperThread();
    mLooperThread.start();
```

> and when you need to update :

```
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("ADD", add);
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            msg.setData(bundle);
            mLooperThread.mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
```

Comment: no this is not working, again i can able to get the value of add and its not updating in textview

Comment: @Madhu what did you mean "can get the add value"?

Comment: @Madhu is `add` value not empty? I mean is not a `""`?

Comment: yeah, its not empty i can get the exact address

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81268/discussion-between-madhu-and-sergey-shustikov).

Answer (score 1):

```
//Global Initialize
 String add = "";// not null

 final Handler handler = new Handler();
                                Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {


                                    public void run() {
                                        add = Util.getLocationCityName(
                                                String.valueOf(ltlng.latitude),
                                                String.valueOf(ltlng.longitude));

                                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                            public void run() {

                                                LogUtil.d("add" + add);//i can get the add value
                                                vImei.setText(add);
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                };

                                new Thread(runnable).start();
```

I hope it helps you.. :)

Comment: i have initialized add

Comment: @Madhu :- is it globally declared? you have to "add" parameter declared globally.

Comment: @Madhu :- difficulty only text which data not set? have find id of TextView?

Comment: yes i have find the id of TextView, for your information i have tried to do thread in map infowindow, will it make any issue??

Answer (score 1):

Please try this,

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
                            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                                String add = null;

                                public void run() {
                                    add = Util.getLocationCityName(
                                            String.valueOf(ltlng.latitude),
                                            String.valueOf(ltlng.longitude));

                                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
           LogUtil.d("add" + add);//i can get the add value
                                            vImei.setText(add);
        }
    });
                                }
                            };

                            new Thread(runnable).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

An other solution which solves your problem is the usage of an AsyncTask

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>(){

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // runs on its own thread
            return Util.getLocationCityName(
                    String.valueOf(ltlng.latitude),
                    String.valueOf(ltlng.longitude));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // runs on the UI Thread to Update your Views
            LogUtil.d("add" + result);
            vImei.setText(result);

        }
    };

    asyncTask.execute();
```

Comment: here also i can get the value of add, but its not updating in textview

Comment: Thats kind of strange. But your code works if you are not using threads?